# How can i get a remote endpoint at UDPClient?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sockets

I'm making a server app, and i need to know, from which address message has come to the server. At `Socket` class has a `RemoteEndPoint` to get know where message come from. Is it have some solution to find where message come from at `UDPClient` class? I searched web, but didn't find something about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have not posted any code, this is a simplified example, that should get the job done:

```
UdpClient udp = new UdpClient(5050);
private void Listen()
{
    while (true)
    {
         IPEndPoint anyIP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
         byte[] recData = udp.Receive(ref anyIP);
         string ip = anyIP.Address.ToString() //this is client IP address
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works great! I didn't said at the question, but i wanted to get a port, where it comes from, so as you said, but just instead `Address`, should using `Port`. Thanks again!

Comment: Edited to add the port number as well. It's part of the IPEndpoint object

Comment: This did not work in my case. I only got the IP address of the receiving NIC. What can I do? (Code runs in a Backgroundworker and is already stripped down to this example; Setup: Sending program in a VM (IP: *.3, host-Network adapter, Send to broadcast (255.255.255.255)) receiving program on host (IP: *.1). "anyIP.Adress" == *.1)